# How to deploy modified airflow dag from a different start time?

Tags: python, airflow

Lets say scheduler is stopped for 5 hours and I had dag scheduled for twice every hour. Now when I restart the scheduler I do not want to airflow to backfill all the instances those were missed, Instead I want it to continue from the current hour.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this behavior, you can use the `LatestOnlyOperator`, which was just recently [introduced to master](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/1752), to the start of your DAG. It is not currently part of a released version though (1.7.1.3 is the latest version as of the writing of this post).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're no longer waiting for an answer, but for reference, this is covered here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls.

> "When needing to change your start_date and schedule interval, change the name of the dag (a.k.a. dag_id) - I follow the convention : my_dag_v1, my_dag_v2, my_dag_v3, my_dag_v4, etc..."

Comment: if we change the dag_id, we are also gonna be losing the historical run statistics.